# test an async function has thrown an exception using sinon and chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

I have this exported function:

```
module.exports.doThing = async (input) => {
  if(input === '') { throw('no input present') }
  // other stuff
  return input
}
```

and a test file for it, in which I'm trying to test that an error is thrown when input is invalid.  This is what I've tried:

```
const testService = require('../services/testService.js')
const chai = require('chai')
const expect = chai.expect
const sinon = require('sinon')
chai.use(require('sinon-chai'))

describe('doThing', () => {
  it('throws an exception if input is not present', async () => {
    expect(testService.doThing('')).to.be.rejected
  })
})
```

I'm getting the error `Error: Invalid Chai property: rejected` and also `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

How can I fix this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to install the plugin [`chai-as-promised`](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/). This allows you to do the following:

```
const testService = require('../services/testService.js')
const chai = require('chai')
    .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('doThing', () => {
    it('throws an exception if input is not present', async () => {
        await expect(testService.doThing('')).to.be.rejectedWith('no input present');
    });
    it('should not throw ...', async () => {
        await expect(testService.doThing('some input')).to.be.fulfilled;
    });
})
```